# FFmpeg MSVC Compilation stuck

Tags: c++, build, ffmpeg, compilation

For several days now I try to build the FFmpeg Libraries. I'm using Windows7 64 Bit and MSVC2010. I followed this guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC

I got rid of a view errors and configure is working finally. But when I try make, it runs for like half an hour and then gets stuck. It won't proceed, I kept it running over night and nothing happend. I also tried different compiler options but it gets stuck every time at the same point.

```
ffv1dec.o_converted.c
d:\cpplibraries\ffmpeg-master\libavcodec\get_bits.h(308) : warning C4101: 're_cache' : unreferenced local variable
d:\cpplibraries\ffmpeg-master\libavcodec\golomb.h(360) : warning C4245: '=' : conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
```

I also tried setting up a minGW64 Msys2 Environment but have the same issue there.
I also tried another setup but when I get rid of some errors I always get stuck at the exact same position.

The cl.exe is running and is using memory but nothing happens.

I also get a ton of warnings like conversions from int to unsigned int, Makro redefinitions, etc.

I have no idea where to look to fix this, so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Warnings indicate non-clean code which looks suspicuous somehow to the compiler. This does not mean that code won't running. (Although it is better to write clean code which compiles without any warning.) As you described it it seems that your compiler didn't complete. From my experience, MSVC may generate intermediate code with surprising huge size. E.g. we definitely have less than 100 MB source code (.cc files, .h files, etc.) in our company's productive code but I often recognized multiple Giga bytes of additional (intermediate) files after compiling. Check the left space on your disk...

Comment: I have over 300GB left, I changed from C drive to D because I had the Problem before, but That's not it now. Even if I try compiling another Version of FFmpeg or with different options, it always gets stuck at the exact same Line.
In the config.log file there are listes several errors, which I'm not sure how to handle. Altering the Code is no option, and this errors shouldn't occur in the first place... I'm pretty new to compiling and so on, but it's not the first time. Stil... I don't really know what to do now.

Comment: I got the same problem at the same point in Visual Studio 2010 too. The cl.exe ran over 4 hours without disk I/O.

Comment: If I run a previous Version (I tried 2.8) it compiles successfully. Only Problem is I need some filters which come with Version 3.x. I don't know what exactly you want to do with ffmpeg, but maybe that would solve your Problem. I will now try to disable a few things, maybe I don't actually need where exactly it gets stuck. Although I would really like to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I solved this by modifying libavcodec\ffv1enc.c:

```
//#if FF_API_CODER_TYPE
static const AVCodecDefault ffv1_defaults[] = {
    { "coder", "-1" },
    { NULL },
};
//#endif
//#if FF_API_CODER_TYPE
    .defaults       = ffv1_defaults,
//#endif
```